# Changing file path on IIS site while the site is UP

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, iis-7, web

While my site is running on IIS, I plan to change the Physical Path of the site.

Is it Okay to just change Physical Path while the site is running?

I wanted to not **STOP** the site, but to just keep it running.

Thanks!

Comment: are you using domain (ex. www.site.com)?

Comment: Yes. I'm using a domain.

Comment: instead of changing the phsical path of the current web application, create a new one and put your domain to it.

Comment: Is there a specific reason for that? I wanted to create new path for a specific build, then just switch to different path every time needed. Is there a bad implementation there?

Comment: with my implementation you will have two web application working side by side with different build compare with yours you will only have one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It's ok and you can do so but notice that your web app would be restarted.

It means that if your app is using inproc sessions, all session variables would be removed. If you're using Sessions with State Server or SQL, then that's fine.